# Fix old links to Activities profile tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, broken-link

In the past day or two, the profile tab for 'activities' was changed to 'all actions'.  Part of this included a change to the URL parameter for that tab, `?tab=activities` became `?tab=allactions`.  If you attempt to access `?tab=activities`, you're presented with a 404 (or if you're a mod, you get a "Could not find a user or deletion record" page, which was hilarious when I loaded that URL for my own profile).  That seems like a terrible reaction to loading a long-time functional tab, so I submit this feature request.

Create a redirect so when someone tries to load `?tab=activities`, they're redirected to `?tab=allactions`.  This then means tools that loaded the activities tab continue to function, and URLs don't break in confusing manners.  An alternative to this would be to just load the user's profile page, since we provided an invalid parameter in the URL, we didn't load a completely garbage URL.